# How to change the image source inside controltemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have template in my **MyResourceDictionary.xaml** file like this

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="ImageButtonTemplatepurpleSmall"  >
        <Grid>
            <Image Source="images\button_purple_up_76.jpg" Name="image"  />

        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Source" Value="images\button_purple_hover_76.jpg" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Source" Value="images\button_purple_depressed_76.jpg" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Which is for applying image to button now 
I just want to change this **image source** of this image inside grid like this
This is what i have tried

```
Image RecTangleObj = (Image)btnBack.Template.FindName("image", btnBack);
```

but some how it's always returns null value how can i change the image source of this one ?
**updated**

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            //base.OnApplyTemplate();
            //Image RecTangleObj = (Image)btnBack.Template.FindName("image", btnBack);
            //if (RecTangleObj != null)
            //{ 

            //}
        }
```

Comment: Where are you putting this code? Is template already applied on button? I suspect you are doing it in constructor of control.

Comment: yes template is already applied i want to change that image if user have uploaded new image @RohitVats

Comment: Please check the answer and let me know in case it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OnApplyTemplate of window gets called when no child content is rendered on screen.

Place this code in `Loaded` event and it will work fine.

Comment: Ya its working great thanks i just have one more question i want to change image without referencing  btnBack so all button connected to this have new image applied

Comment: First of all you should not do it from code behind. Have proper property in ViewModel and bind with that (that's proper way of doing it) and on any change set that property so it gets update automatically. If you still want to do this way, you have to use reference of button :(

Comment: ok but i have upload button so is there any suggestion for this one? using viewmodel?

Comment: You need to bind source to some property in ViewModel. Have you worked in MVVM? This is sample how to do it `<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"/>`. But in case you haven't worked on it then you need to learn that first. There are lot of articles available over net.

Comment: That's whole lot of new question. So, I would suggest for follow up question post another question here at SO so that it can be looked upon by larger audience here.